# Why my hashmap is null Android?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

i am trying to get the value from the hashmap (from ListViewRestaurants) So i can pass the latitude and longitude to the MapsActivity but for reason my hashmap always return null ... So can Anyone help me.

```
public class ListViewRestaurants extends Activity {

    static ListView listView;
    static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listiew);
        arrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        String json_str = getJsonData();

        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json_str);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = null;
                json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map1.put("id", json.getString("id"));
                map1.put("BusinessName", json.getString("BusinessName"));
                map1.put("AddressLine1", json.getString("AddressLine1"));
                map1.put("AddressLine2", json.getString("AddressLine2"));
                map1.put("AddressLine3", json.getString("AddressLine3"));
                map1.put("PostCode", json.getString("PostCode"));
                map1.put("RatingValue", json.getString("RatingValue"));
                map1.put("RatingDate", json.getString("RatingDate"));
                map1.put("DistanceKM", json.getString("DistanceKM"));
                map1.put("Latitude", json.getString("Latitude"));
                map1.put("Longitude", json.getString("Longitude"));

                int name = json.getInt("RatingValue");
                if(name == 5){
                    map1.put("Image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher_web));
                }
                else if(name==4){
                    //map1.put("Image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher_web));
                }
                else if(name==3){
                    // map1.put("Image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher_web));
                }
                else if(name==2){
                    // map1.put("Image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher_web));
                }
                else if(name==1){
                    // map1.put("Image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher_web));
                }
                else if(name==0){
                    // map1.put("Image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher_web));
                }
                else if(name==-1){
                    map1.put("RatingValue", "Exempt");
                }
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                arrList.add(map1); //                Intent intent = new Intent(this,MapsActivity.class); //                intent.putExtra("map", map1);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!arrList.isEmpty()) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"id", "BusinessName",
                    "AddressLine1", "AddressLine2", "AddressLine3", "PostCode",
                    "RatingValue", "RatingDate", "DistanceKM", "Image"},
                    new int[]{R.id.restaurantId, R.id.BusinessName,
                            R.id.adr1, R.id.adr2, R.id.adr3, R.id.postCode,
                            R.id.rating, R.id.ratingDate, R.id.distance, R.id.image});


            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    private String getJsonData() {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectDiskReads()
                .detectDiskWrites()
                .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());

        String str = "";
        Intent intent  = getIntent();
        String latitude = intent.getStringExtra("Lat");
        String longtitude = intent.getStringExtra("Lon");
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://sandbox.kriswelsh.com/hygieneapi/hygiene.php?op=s_loc&lat="+latitude+"&long="+longtitude);

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;
    }

}
```

Here i am trying to retrieve details from the hashamp (latitude and longitude) from the ListViewRestuarants but i always get null values.

```
import android.content.Intent; import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory; import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback; import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment; import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    static String x;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        //get the value from the array class
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map"); System.out.println(hashmap)


       // Log.v("HashMapTest", hashMap.get("Longtitude"));
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(x));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    } }
```

This is a main class which display tab view (for more information)

```
import android.app.TabActivity; import android.content.Intent; import android.os.Bundle; import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
        TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");

        // Set the Tab name and Activity
        // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected
        tab1.setIndicator("Restaurant");
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, ListViewRestaurants.class));

        tab2.setIndicator("Map");
        tab2.setContent(new Intent(this, RestaurantMap.class));

        /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    } }
```

Comment: Well for starters, un-commenting the code where you are setting the extras would help.

Comment: Are you getting a NullPointerException? At what point is the map null?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are setting a different key in the map but trying to fetch the value corresponding to a different key -

```
map1.put("Longitude", json.getString("Longitude")); //Setting "Longitude"

Log.v("HashMapTest", hashMap.get("Longtitude")); //Getting "Longtitude"
```

Apparently, there is no key "`Longtitude`" in your map.

Best practice is to have constants for keys and use it for insertion and retrieval  and this will avoid such issues and will not waste your time debugging in  also.